# Resetting a nested list while maintaining structure

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

Is it possible to "clear" out a (nested) list in python while maintaining the "structure". I mean that if the input it is

```
[1,3,4,[5,2,[4,3],3],6,[7,8],9]
```

The output would be

```
[0,0,0,[0,0,[0,0],0],0,[0,0],0]
```

Where the actual structure of the list is maintained and just the values are reset.

**Context:** There actually isn't any, this question just came to mind and I was wondering if it can be done. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation that makes use of the duck typing principle:

```
In [5]: def clear(seq):
   ...:     for i, item in enumerate(seq):
   ...:         try:
   ...:             clear(item)
   ...:         except TypeError:
   ...:             try:
   ...:                 seq[i] = 0
   ...:             except IndexError, KeyError:
   ...:                 pass
   ...:             

In [6]: s = [1,3,4,[5,2,[4,3],3],6,[7,8],9]

In [9]: clear(s)

In [10]: s
Out[10]: [0, 0, 0, [0, 0, [0, 0], 0], 0, [0, 0], 0]
```

The advantage to this is that you aren't restricted to structures/values that are `int`s or `list`s. This function will 'zero' out any mutable structure which supports indexing.

Comment: Okay, I had to accept this. Pythonic. Although, I didn't know `KeyError` and `IndexError` were subtypes of `TypeError`

Comment: @Sabyasachi: They're not. `KeyError` and `IndexError` are both subclassed from `LookupError`. The nesting of `try...except` clauses doesn't indicate inheritance.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: So you accepted this one with nested try/except stucture since it is more, well, Pythonic. However you explicitely lists in your question. Nevermind. Just call `clear('Clear this one!')`. No offense Joel.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam It's just my opinion. I liked your solution as well, and upvoted it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [1,3,4,[5,2,[4,3],3],6,[7,8],9]
>>> def reset(lst):
...     return [reset(e) if isinstance(e, list) else 0 for e in lst]
...
>>> l = reset(l)
>>> l
[0, 0, 0, [0, 0, [0, 0], 0], 0, [0, 0], 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work using recursion, although it is a bit primitive.

#### Note: ints and lists only but can be any random nesting. Works for all

```
def set_zero(lst):
    for i,element in enumerate(lst):
        if type(element) != list: lst[i]=0
        else: set_zero(element)

>>> a = [1,3,4,[5,2,[4,3],3],6,[7,8],9]
>>> set_zero(a)
>>> print(a)
[0,0,0,[0,0,[0,0],0],0,[0,0],0]
```

Nice question by the way!

Comment: (+1)Brilliant. I think you remove the "integer only" condition by re-writing the if as `if type(element)!=list`. Cheers.

Comment: Ah while you're at it, you have a typo in the output.

Comment: @Sabyasachi, Where is the typo?

Comment: I see a `6` in the output

Comment: @Sabyasachi, Waaaa..., I completely missed that. But that is not a typo in the code, I simply copied your list and changed the values manually. :P

Comment: I know it isn't a typo in the code, I meant it was a typo when you were manually changing. :) I will wait for a few hours to see if something else crops up, otherwise accepting this(as you admit it is a little verbose, but maybe better can't be done).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find another method, which is basically cheating but it works.
Also, it is a **one-liner**!!

```
def set_zero(lst):
    return eval(''.join(str(0) if x.isdigit() else str(x) for x in str(lst)))

>>> a = [1,3,4,[5,2,[4,3],3],6,[7,8],9]
>>> a = set_zero(a)
>>> print(a)
[0,0,0,[0,0,[0,0],0],0,[0,0],0]
```

Downside:
It is 3 / 4 X slower than my previous suggestion.

```
Method 1: ~0.000035 s
Method 2: ~0.000120 s
```

I posted it as a different answer since it is a completely different concept. I can merge it back into my first answer if you want.

Comment: +1 brilliant. I am accepting the other though, eval *is* cheating(:p) the other answer captures your idea for the recursive call in a one liner.